# How to read Collection.System.Collections.Generic.ICollection Items

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

One of my api will return ICollection result, I would like read them in my code without using System.Linq. Will it possible ?

Adding more--- 
When I use Linq , ICollection.First().Value is fine.. I want way which should work like same as with out using Linq.

Thanks
Pavan

Comment: Why not just a basic `IEnumerable`?

Comment: `.First` is part of LINQ....you want LINQ without LINQ?!

Comment: if i want to read specific element Just like ICollection.First().Value

Comment: Will it possible elements/Items to read like LINQ API

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can simply use a foreach-loop.

Edit: to access a specific element you can use the index access like in the other answers. If you need a specific condition, you can iterate the collection

```
ICollection<TYPE> collection = YourApi();
TYPE result; 

foreach(var x in collection)
{
    if( your condition is true )
    {
        result = x;
        break;       
    }
}

// check if result is not null and use it
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `foreach` loop :

```
foreach(var elem in mycollection)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

**Edit :**

For the `ICollection.First()` you can do :

```
if (mycollection.Count > 0)
    var firstItem = mycollection[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

`ICollection` extends `IEnmerable`. This means that it returns an enumerator and can be looped over with a `ForEach` loop. This does not require `Linq`.

Answer (score 0):

Any object supporting LINQ queries will support foreach also. You can use foreach:

```
foreach(item in collection)
{
    //work with item
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, you can use foreach to access all elements in your collection. You keep saying "i want to read specific element Just like ICollection.First().Value".

If you want to mimic First()'s functionality, you need to write an extension method for ICollection:

```
public static class ExMethods
{
   public static object First<T>(this ICollection<T> collection)
   {
     foreach (var x in collection)
     {
       return x;
     }
     //throw exception if colletion is empty
   }
}
```

Or just use Linq! :)